# Egrep command hangs when passed a file for Regex patterns

Tags: regex, performance, shell, grep, cygwin

NB: I'm using Cygwin.

Passing in a file into the egrep command to use patterns is running incredibly slowly (to the point where after the 4th word match, it was more than 5 minutes before I gave up).
The command I'm trying to run is:

```
 cat words.txt | egrep ^"[A-Z]" | egrep -f words9.txt
```

*words.txt* is a dictionary (390K words), and *words9.txt* is a file (36,148 words) I created that contains all lowercase 9-letter words from *word.txt*.
This command should find any 10+ letter words that contain a 9-letter word from *words9.txt*.

I am new to regex and shell commands so it may be simply that this file dependency is an incredibly inefficient method, (having to search 36148 words for every word in words.txt). Is there a better way of tackling this?

Comment: If `words9.txt` doesn't have regexes try adding `--fixed-strings` to the second `egrep` filter. I don't think that amount of data can take so long.

Comment: What would the new filter look like with that added? I'm getting usage errors wherever I put it with "grep: unknown option", is there a package or something I'm missing from the cygwin install? I stuck to all the defaults.
EDIT: My apologies I accidentally typed --fixed--strings, but I'm still getting "grep: conflicting matchers specified"

Comment: Sorry, `egrep` is for extended regex, I meant just fixed search, that's `grep -F` or `fgrep`, try `cat words.txt | egrep "^[A-Z]" | grep -F -f words9.txt` (leaving the caret outside the quoting feels really weird for me :P)

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. What is the reason that grep supports it while egrep doesn't?

Comment: `egrep` uses the regex engine, `grep -F` or `fgrep` uses fixed string search. They are mutually exclusive, so, there's no reason for egrep to have that option.

Comment: Minor point: I would rename `words9.txt -> dict9.txt` to make it clear what it is, and that it's unrelated to `words.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `words9.txt` doesn't have regexes try using a fixed string search (`fgrep` or `grep -F`) instead of using the extended regex search (`egrep`).

```
cat words.txt | egrep "^[A-Z]" | fgrep -f words9.txt
```

Comment: Psssst.  Useless use of cat.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat.  Save a process and some overhead by using: egrep "^[A-Z]" words.txt | fgrep -f words9.txt

Comment: Totally agree, besides I read that `egrep` and `fgrep` are deprecated in favor of `grep -E` and `grep -F`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to improve on `egrep ^"[A-Z]" words.txt | egrep -f words9.txt`

Your `words9.txt` is **not** a file of regex patterns, it's only fixed strings, so treating it as such (`grep -F`) will generally be much faster, as @KurzedMetal said.

Mind you, if its contents had a lot of overlap near-duplicates, you could manually merge them by constructing regexes, here's how you'd do that:

- Get a list of all 9-letter words starting with 'inter' (using the Unix builtin word dict)
- `awk 'length($0)==9' /usr/share/dict/words`
- now say you wanted to merge all 9-letter words starting with the 5 characters 'inter' into one regex. First let's get them as a list: `grep "^inter" | paste -sd ',' -` gives:

  > interalar,interally,interarch,interarmy,interaxal,interaxis,interbank,interbody,intercale,intercalm,intercede,intercept,intercity,interclub,intercome,intercrop,intercurl,interdash,interdict,interdine,interdome,interface,interfere,interflow,interflux,interfold,interfret,interfuse,intergilt,intergrow,interhyal,interject,interjoin,interknit,interknot,interknow,interlace,interlaid,interlake,interlard,interleaf,interline,interlink,interloan,interlock,interloop,interlope,interlude,intermaze,intermeet,intermelt,interment,intermesh,intermine,internals,internist,internode,interpage,interpave,interpeal,interplay,interplea,interpole,interpone,interpose,interpour,interpret,interrace,interroad,interroom,interrule,interrupt,intersale,intersect,intershop,intersole,intertalk,interteam,intertill,intertone,intertown,intertwin,intervale,intervary,intervein,intervene,intervert,interview,interweld,interwind,interwish,interword,interwork,interwove,interwrap,interzone`
- The regex would start with: `inter(a(l(ar|ly)|r(ch|my)|x(al|is))|b(...)|c(...)|...)`. We're implementing a tree structure from L-to-R (there are other ways but this is the obvious way).
- Testing it: `grep "^inter" words9.txt | egrep '^intera(l(ar|ly)|r(ch|my)|x(al|is))'`

  > interalar
  >     interally
  >     interarch
  >     interarmy
  >     interaxal
  >     interaxis

Yay! But it may still be faster to just have a plain list of fixed-strings. Also, this regex will be harder to maintain, brittle etc. Impossible to easily filter or remove specific strings. Anyway you get the point. PS I'm sure there are automated tools out there that construct regexes for such wordlists.